# C++ Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF when using __func__ identifier

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2017, predefined-variables

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I set the project to use ISO C++14 Standard under C/C++->Languages

The debugger cannot recognize `__func__` predefined identifier and it crashes if I try to use it as a string with error:

`: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

What am I missing to be able to use this identifier?

Code sample if needed

`printf("%S\n", __func__);`

Thanks

Comment: Can you attach a small, compilabe example with which the error occurs?

Comment: *and it crashes if I try to use it as a string with error:* -- Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show *what* you're trying to do with it?

Comment: really? you need me to add a printf function to a string.

Comment: Why are you using `%S` as the format string?  This seems to be a case of using `printf` incorrectly, not that `__func__` cannot be used.  And if this is C++, why not take the extra step of trying `cout` instead of `printf` to see if that is an issue?

Comment: %S is for `wchar_t` but `__func__` is a `const char`.

Comment: Take precisely example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2017 and try it out do not change %s to %S

Comment: Also, doesn't Visual C++ 17 warn you of the format string not matching the argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static const char __func__[];
```

`printf()`  with a capital `S` as a conversion specifier is an extension that requires a `wchar_t*`.

Solution, use a lowercase `s`:

```
printf("%s\n", __func__);
```

or

```
std::cout << __func__ << '\n';
```